# What does the empirical literature tell us about the relative merits of alternative functional forms describing the marginal utility of income?

Tags: expected-utility, risk-aversion, social-choice, functional-form

Among the various functional forms that have been used on model the marginal utility of income in, e.g., in making decisions under uncertainty, and perhaps intertemporal choice as well, is the available data adequate to discriminate between forms that more accurately account  for observable behavior and those that, despite some intuitive attractiveness or analytical tractability, fit observed behavior less well? I have been collecting papers in the (rather tendentious and ideological) literature on attempts to measure the marginal utility of money or income, and now have some 62 papers, but I have not yet found a good literature review that addresses these questions, and would welcome, not only an explicit answer to the question above, but also a citation to a well-written paper that summarizes what is known.

The best papers I have found on roughly this question come from the literature arising from interpreting utility as a measure of happiness. Although I know this approach was h.istorically important and has gained traction over the last 20 years or so, largely due to advances in neuroscience, I think utility is better regarded as an index of freedom, reflecting the range of economic choices available or the desirability of the actual consumption choices made relative to the choices that would have been made under a tighter budget constraint.